# Display previous element in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have got one array of objects.I am trying below one after filtering all "@KAV":"1" objects.

```
let finalArray=kavArray[index-1];
```

All the "@KAV":"1" object present in the **kavArray**.

How can i display  those items before satisfying the condition where "@KAV":"1" is present?

Thanks.

```
         [
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
            "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
            "@TAARIF": "104135.00",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
            "@KAV": "2"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
            "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
            "@KAVUA": "9",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
            "@SEMEL": "1",
            "@KAV": "0"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
            "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
            "@SEMEL": "101",
            "@KAV": "0"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "שכר בסיס",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13702.67",
            "@KAV": "1"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
            "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
            "@TAARIF": "182.55",
            "@KAMUT": "1.00",
            "@KAVUA": "מק",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
            "@SEMEL": "90",
            "@KAV": "0"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "החזר הוצאות",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
            "@KAV": "1"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק",
            "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
            "@KAVUA": "או",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
            "@SEMEL": "73",
            "@KAV": "0"
          },
          {
            "@USEFORMAT": "1",
            "@TEUR": "מענקים",
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
            "@KAV": "1"
          },
          
          
        ]
```

How can i achieve those elements?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript's `filter` method to accomplish that.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
    "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
    "@TAARIF": "104135.00",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
    "@KAV": "2"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
    "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
    "@KAVUA": "9",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
    "@SEMEL": "1",
    "@KAV": "0"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
    "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
    "@SEMEL": "101",
    "@KAV": "0"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "שכר בסיס",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13702.67",
    "@KAV": "1"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
    "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
    "@TAARIF": "182.55",
    "@KAMUT": "1.00",
    "@KAVUA": "מק",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
    "@SEMEL": "90",
    "@KAV": "0"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "החזר הוצאות",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
    "@KAV": "1"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק",
    "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6",
    "@KAVUA": "או",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
    "@SEMEL": "73",
    "@KAV": "0"
  },
  {
    "@USEFORMAT": "1",
    "@TEUR": "מענקים",
    "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
    "@KAV": "1"
  },


];

const result = arr.filter(item => item["@KAV"] === "1");
console.log(result);
```

documentation for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.filter()` to filter the elements whose next item has key/value `@KAV:"1"`

```js
const kavArray = [ { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום", "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6", "@TAARIF": "104135.00", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13", "@KAV": "2" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד", "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6", "@KAVUA": "9", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00", "@SEMEL": "1", "@KAV": "0" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות", "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67", "@SEMEL": "101", "@KAV": "0" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "שכר בסיס", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13702.67", "@KAV": "1" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה", "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6", "@TAARIF": "182.55", "@KAMUT": "1.00", "@KAVUA": "מק", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55", "@SEMEL": "90", "@KAV": "0" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "החזר הוצאות", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55", "@KAV": "1" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק", "@SUG_TASHLUM": "6", "@KAVUA": "או", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00", "@SEMEL": "73", "@KAV": "0" }, { "@USEFORMAT": "1", "@TEUR": "מענקים", "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00", "@KAV": "1" }, ]


const filteredArray = kavArray.filter((item, index) => kavArray[index+1] && kavArray[index+1]["@KAV"] === "1")

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: I want to display each "@KAV":"1" before objects.@Harun Yilmaz

Comment: @Chinmayee I'm not sure I understand the desired output. Can you provide it also?